# ORA-00947: not enough values on FROM

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My code just work if I try the query on the worksheet of sql developer the sql but if I try to use the query inside my procedure I've this error:
ORA-00947: not enough values on FROM of the query.

```
        select /*+ ALL_ROWS */
               x.cd_anno,X.CD_PERIODO,x.cd_istituto,x.id_accesso,
               x.cd_tipo_trasm, x.cd_ident_univoco,
               x.cd_istituzione_team, x.cd_sesso,x.dt_nascita,x.cd_eta_presunta,
               x.cd_cittadinanza,x.cd_istat_res,x.cd_regione_res,
    decode(x.cd_stato_estero_res,'UK','GB','EL','GR','FL','LI',x.cd_stato_estero_res) cd_stato_estero_res,
               x.cd_asl_res,x.dt_entrata,
               x.cd_ora_entrata,x.cd_mod_arrivo,x.cd_centrale_oper,
               x.cd_missione,x.cd_resp_invio,x.cd_istituto_prov,
               x.cd_problema_principale,x.cd_trauma,x.cd_triage,
               x.dt_presa_carico,x.cd_ora_presa_carico,x.cd_esito,          
   DECODE(nvl(x.dt_dimissione,'00000000'),'00000000',x.dt_entrata,x.dt_dimissione),
                   x.cd_ora_dimissione,x.cd_referto,
                   x.cd_livello_appr,x.cd_spec_reparto,x.nr_prog_ricovero,
                   x.cd_motivo_trasf,x.cd_istituto_trasf,x.cd_regime_erog,
                   x.nr_imp_ticket,x.cd_pos_ticket,x.cd_esenzione,
                   x.cd_diagnosi_1,x.cd_diagnosi_2,x.fl_anonimizzazione,
                   x.fl_da_inviare,x.dt_insert,x.dt_update,
                   z.nr_validato, z.cd_cuni, z.cd_tipo_cf, z.cd_fiscale
            BULK COLLECT INTO rec_ps1ps2
              from ps_invio_mds_ps1_ps2 x join CUNI_VALIDAZIONE z on 
                  x.cd_ident_univoco = z.cd_fiscale 
             where x.cd_anno = p_anno
               and x.fl_da_inviare = 'Y'
             order by x.cd_anno,x.cd_istituto,x.id_accesso;
```

Can you help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a good start!

Comment: What's the type of rec_ps1ps2? Are you sure it matches the result of your query?

Comment: How many fields are there in the underlying record type for the `rec_ps1ps2` collection? I'm guessing not the same number as you have select-list items (50?). If it still isn't obvious to you, edit your question to show the type declarations; and probably the table definitions too.

Comment: can you post `rec_ps1ps2` structure? is it a row structure?

Comment: So, I noticed that I have 1 more field, is there any way to add a field? 
here is the code of rec_ps1ps2:

 TYPE rec_ps1ps2 IS TABLE OF ps_invio_mds_ps1_ps2%ROWTYPE NOT NULL
    INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

Comment: @GiulioAngioli - only by either (a) modifying the table you're getting the rowtype from; or (b) defining your own record type that duplicates all the columns from that table plus your extra one, and basing your collection on that.

Comment: @AlexPoole okay, thank you all for support!

Comment: @GiulioAngioli - You're at least missing `DECODE(nvl(x.dt_dimissione,'00000000'),'00000000',x.dt_entrata,x.dt_dimissione)` (which you should also alieas `as some_column`; may be use dt_dimissione or dt_entrata?). You're also missing `z.nr_validato, z.cd_cuni, z.cd_tipo_cf, z.cd_fiscale` as far as I can see. Everything else is taken from the `ps_invio_mds_ps1_ps2`, that is, of course if you didn't repeat any column in the select statement (like you did with dt_entrata).